# Saber se valor vindo de um input é um link de XX site. PHP - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um site que nele teria o perfil do facebook, mas estamos com medo que algum espertinho coloque qualquer link lá, alguém teria uma dica ou um modo de fazer para verificar se o link é do facebook, isto é possível ou estou viajando? Estou recebendo o possível link assim:

```
$this->Usuario_model->perfil_facebook = $this->input->post('link');
```

Obrigado a quem conseguir responder.

Comment: Como é um link do perfil do facebook? tem um formato especifico?

Comment: seria o link do perfil da pessoa tipo https://www.facebook.com/meu_perfil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível verificar se o endereço passado é uma URL válida do Facebook. A primeira que me vem em mente é:
- Toda URL de perfil do facebook deve começar com "http://facebook.com/" ou https.

Sendo assim, você pode utilizar substrings ou expressões regulares para validar, por exemplo:

```
$url_facebook = $this->input->post('link');

// Passa: http://facebook.com/user/teste123
// Passa: https://facebook.com/user/teste123
// Erro: http://teste.com/user/teste123

if (preg_match("~^https?://facebook.com/.*~", $url_facebook) == 0) {
    // URL inválida
    echo "URL invalida";
}
```

Só é preciso ter o cuidado e validar todos os endereços possíveis para perfis no facebook.

Comment: Atenção, que www.fb.com é o mesmo que www.facebook.com...

Comment: @PedroLuzio acho que nesse caso o mais importante é a lógica. O ideal é permitir um formato só e avisar o usuário que só são aceitos endereços começados por http(s)://facebook.com - o fb.com mesmo é mero redirect.

Comment: Pensei em ir-se pelo ip associado ao url